# How do I make unique actions base on the database data using buttons

Tags: php

I have `id`, `name` and `surname` in my database then i want a button on each row that will send row data to someone's email (e.g id : 1. Name: John).

```
<?php
`$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test')`;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user";

    $results = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    $check_results = mysqli_num_rows($results);

    if ($check_results > 0) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){

    $id = $row['id'];

    echo "<input type='button' name='send' value='$id'>";

    }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
    // then send data(email) on a row where button is clicked
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

create a form, set action to your php file to send email, create hidden input with id value for each row then your button with submit type will work.

Comment: Thank you. i find your answer helpful